# Dump Windows 11 PIN hash

Tags: hash, windows, hashcat

Can anyone tell me how to dump the Windows 11 PIN? I tried dumping SAM and SYSTEM but the PIN hash is not there. What mode we can use in hashcat to crack it?

Comment: I googled "windows 11 pin hash" and this was the top hit: https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-10461.html Did you see that or use any of its recommendations? The duplicate linked above was also in the top hits. And this this below that: https://superuser.com/questions/1414966/where-is-the-windows-10-pin-stored  Please make sure that you have done at least a little research before posting questions.